# Digital board for meeting rooms - Office 365 - OAuth2 - Token life that never expire

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0, office365, token, azure-active-directory

I'm working on a **digital board for meeting rooms**. Every board, set outside the door of the meeting room, displays if it's occupied or not and the following meetings, according to it's calendar.
I followed this tutorial to create a [**JavaScript single-page app**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial?hubRefSrc=email&utm_source=lfemail&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=lfnotification#lf-content=194929213:782092581&reply_editor=true).

The problem is that after a while (less than 1 hour) I have to do the log-in again. I'm really struggling to find a solution to avoid it at all or reduce this frequency as much as possible.

Looking around it seems that working on **the life of the Token is the answer**. Refresh it or, even better, set it that never expires (until-revoked).

I've tried with PowerShell, following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) but it doesn't work for the v2.0.

Comment: Are you sure that this is available in your Azure AD? The link given says, "This capability currently is in Public Preview. Be prepared to revert or remove any changes."

Comment: Adding code that checks for the current lifetime of the token is trivial. Try to think simple. The time wasted on searching for this  probably cost you more time already then doing a simple check on the current age of your token.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD does not support infinite lifetime Access Tokens. The hard limit for an Access Token lifetime is 1 hour.

However, Azure AD do support infinite chaining of the refresh token for new access tokens. When you modify the configurable token lifetime property and set it to `until-revoked` you are really doing this for the refresh token.

You must make sure you have proper logic in your code that tracks the expiration time of the access token, and requests for a new access token using the refresh token when the old token expires.

Comment: Hi Shawn,

Many thanks for your reply. Really appreciated!
I've already created a WebApp in AzureAd. My application works on the new Azure space server but the problem is still the same. The token expires and a can't find how to change the parameter regarding its life. Do you know how to do it?